# Is it safe to eat homemade yogurt after a sugar ant fell in it?

Tags: food-safety

I'm so frustrated right now. I just made a gallon of homemade yogurt, only to find a tiny sugar ant has been marinading in it at the top for 24 hours(it's a 24 hour ferment). Is the whole batch spoiled?

Answer (score 13):

Most ant species are edible.  One ant in a gallon of yogurt probably doesn't matter much, aside from you being put off by it.  I would scoop it out and proceed as if it was never there.

Comment: Nothing to worry about, just extra protein.